# Validate and remove the dictionary entry

Tags: python, dictionary

I need to check the python dictionary for one particular value.

Here's an example of the data I'm working with:

Consider the dictionary named record_set.

It consists of values as follows, Each and everyone is different and separate entry.

That is this three were the different dictionaries which is being created while iterating over the loop.

```
{u'name': u'9.8.10.5.in-addr.arpa.',u'domain_id': u'5e18999d'}

{u'name': u'5.6.3.1.in-addr.arpa.',u'domain_id': u'5e18999d'}

{u'name': u'6.5.4.8.in-addr.arpa.',u'domain_id': u'5e18999d'}
```

Now What I need is look for the particular value from dictionary, Consider "6.5.4.8.in-addr.arpa.".

If the values is not present in dictionary that particular dictionary should be discarded.(Should not be returned)

For example results should be as follows:

```
{u'name': u'6.5.4.8.in-addr.arpa.',u'domain_id': u'5e18999d'}
```

Other two entries should be discarded.

I think it is clear now.

Comment: What do you mean by "take the dictionary"? What exactly is supposed to happen if you find that your name is a value in the dictionary? Can you please show some kind of example output?

Comment: It seems that you have a list of dictionaries and you want to loop over these dictonnaries to find a particular value, isn't it ?

Comment: Can you write down your expected outcome? It is not very clear what you intend to do - and your example is not one, but three python dictionaries - is this intentional?

Comment: It looks like you've already written your code. Which part of your task are you having trouble with?

Comment: Now I edited the question to make more sense. please have a look at it now.

Comment: @Murali I thought my edit was clearer and more concise, but w/e. It's understandable now, that's all that matters.

Answer (score 1):

If I'm understanding your problem correctly, you want something like this:

```
records = [{u'name': u'9.8.10.5.in-addr.arpa.',u'domain_id': u'5e18999d'},
{u'name': u'5.6.3.1.in-addr.arpa.',u'domain_id': u'5e18999d'},
{u'name': u'6.5.4.8.in-addr.arpa.',u'domain_id': u'5e18999d'}]

for item in records:
    if item['name'] == '5.6.3.1.in-addr.arpa.':
        print item
```

If you did in fact want to discard the other dictionaries from the list as you mention, you can just have something like this:

```
records = [item for item in records if item['name']=='5.6.3.1.in-addr.arpa.']
```

Link: http://ideone.com/bXhnlr

Comment: Ah, beat me to it. The latter solution is what I would recommend.

Answer (score 0):

I would use a conditional set descriptor:

```
records = [{u'name': u'9.8.10.5.in-addr.arpa.',u'domain_id': u'5e18999d'},
           {u'name': u'5.6.3.1.in-addr.arpa.',u'domain_id': u'5e18999d'},
           {u'name': u'6.5.4.8.in-addr.arpa.',u'domain_id': u'5e18999d'}]
name = u'9.8.10.5.in-addr.arpa.'
matchingRecords = [item for item in records if item[u'name'] == name]
```

matchingRecords would contain: `[{'domain_id': '5e18999d', 'name': '9.8.10.5.in-addr.arpa.'}]`